# Generics: compilation error with the wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, guava, java-7

I've switched to Java 7 build 21 and started getting strange compilation error. For example, the code snippet below does not compile (although IntelliJ doesn't show any errors):

```
    1 Iterable<?> parts = ImmutableList.<String>of("one", "two");
    2 Function<?, String> function = new Function<Object, String>() {
    3    @Override
    4    public String apply(final Object input) {
    5        return input.toString();
    6    }
    7 };
    8 Iterable<String> result = Iterables.transform(parts, function);
    9 System.out.println(result);
```

but if I replace `?` in line 2 to `Object`

```
    2 Function<Object, String> function = new Function<Object, String>() {
```

then the compilation succeeds.

The error I'm getting is somewhat cryptic:

```
error: method transform in class Iterables cannot be applied to given types;
required: Iterable<F>,Function<? super F,? extends T> 
found: Iterable<CAP#1>,Function<CAP#2,String> 
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) F,T exist so that argument type Function<CAP#2,String>
conforms to formal parameter type Function<? super F,? extends T> 
where F,T are type-variables:
F extends Object declared in method <F,T>transform(Iterable<F>,Function<? super F,? extends T>) 
T extends Object declared in method <F,T>transform(Iterable<F>,Function<? super F,? extends T>) 
where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables: 
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
```

Changing line 2 to be

```
    2 Function<? extends Object, String> function = new Function<Object, String>() {
```

has no effect.

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_11-b21; this used to compile ok with build 4.

Is this a `javac` bug or mine?

Comment: Note that there's no value in assigning a `Function<Object, String>` you just created to `Function<?, String>`. You know that it's a `Function<Object, String>` since you just created it, no need to throw away information the compiler has there. As much as possible, the use of wildcards should be restricted to method/constructor parameters. (I imagine the actual code you had this issue with is different, but just saying...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this by changing

```
2 Function<?, String> function = new Function<Object, String>() {
```

to

```
2 Function<? super Object, String> function = new Function<Object, String>() {
```

Which makes sense when you think about it - function is the consumer here (from the infamous [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) idiom).

Comment: Note that `? super Object` could only be `Object`.

Comment: ... which is VERY different from plain <?>

Answer (score 6):

The method signature is:

```
<F,T> Iterable<T> transform(Iterable<F> fromIterable, Function<? super F,? extends T> function)
```

What this means for the type parameter F is:

```
Iterable<F> :
    F can be any type here, but will influence the type parameter to Function
Function<? super F, ? extends T> :
    the first type parameter (? super F) MUST be a supertype of F
```

When you type:

```
Iterable<?>
Function<?, String>
```

You are saying Iterable of anything, so it could be e.g. `Iterable<Integer>`.
You are also saying Function from anything to String, so it could be e.g. `Function<String, String>`.
Since String is not a superclass of Integer, you are  not fulfilling the `(? super F)` condition.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Function<?,String>` could be any of `Function<Object,String>`, `Function<String,String>`, `Function<Foo,String>`. Therefore it's correct that you aren't able to input an Object into the Function, since it could be actually needing a Foo instead.

Of course, since you have `Iterable<?>,` you only know the Iterable spits out Objects, so you can only use a `Function<Object,WhatEver>` to transform it.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it used to work in build 4. Also doesn't explain why `Function<? extends Object, String>` is also wrong.

Comment: @mindas Clearly a subtle wildcard capture bug was since fixed. Also, `? extends Object` is for our purposes the same as `?`, so the same reasoning applies.

Comment: @mindas if it worked in build 4, then i suspect this was actually a bug in build 4. I'm pretty sure this is not supposed to compile.